# Issue with save MSSQL query result into Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I prepare new script to create raport about quantity in stock. I wrote query in MSSQL and now I need save my query result into Excel. I use pandas, pyodbc and ExcelWriter to save result, but I have problem, because DataFrame save my result as object, and when I save query into Excel I have all data in one column (I would like save this into three columns).
What I did:

- I tryed to convert DataFrame object as a list and then export data to file,
- I saved query result into csv and then export to xlsx file
- I used split and explode functions
- I used function to_csv with sep=',' argument
- I checked documentation and other threads

This is one row in my Excel file:
**('01030E4238123', 'POKRYWA SZARA -- 011030E4238', '2715')**
. In my case I need to save this into three columns with columns names ("," is a separator), brackets can be delete.

```
import pyodbc
xlsxFile = ("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\EXCEL_10.xlsx")
sheetName = ("Quantity")
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=IP;DATABASE=DB;UID=ID;PWD=PASS')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ("SELECT * FROM CDN.VIEW_NAME")
cursor.execute(query)
resultQuery = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=resultQuery)
with pd.ExcelWriter(path=xlsxFile, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetName, index=False, header=False, startcol=0)
```

Thanks for any potential tips.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried using  [pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) ? The `data` paremeter of the [DataFrame constructor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) knows only about iterables and dictionaries so it sees `resultQuery` as a single object

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much @PanagiotisKanavos. I spent a one day looking for a solution...
Thank you once again.